# How to display all accessible domains on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, domain

I belong to one specific domain, but I would like to access the other local domains, that I am allowed to browsed, just like on XP (image below).

[image]

Is that even possible to do so in Windows 7 ?

Comment: The image doesn't show domains. It shows network protocols.

Answer (score 2):

In `Network and Sharing Center` which can be found in the `Control Panel`, you'll find a link in the top right corner that says "See full map".

However this functionality will have to be made available by a policy setting for the domain.
I believe the following link should give you some hints on how to do this:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wndp/how-to-enable-the-windows-vista-network-map)